# How to filter a data from api in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to apply the this.global.get(`services/getData.php`) and get/display the data from it.

**list.component.ts**

```
submitForm(): void {
    this.rowData = record.default.records;

    console.log(this.rowData);
    const dateStart = format(this.validateForm.value.datePickerStart, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
    const dateEnd = format(this.validateForm.value.datePickerEnd, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');

    this.rowData = this.rowData.filter((data: templogRecord) => {
      return !isBefore(data.dateandtime, dateStart) && !isAfter(data.dateandtime, dateEnd);
    });
  }
```

I want to use this code.

```
this.global.getData(`/services/getData.php`)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          console.log(res[i]);
        }
      });
```

How to apply this in `submitForm()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to create service for above code then need to call that function from component file by loading in constructor and subscribe that function and you can also use promise for async api call.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is an example of how a service could look like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment'; // Stores all the server links

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public myData(): Observable<any> {
    // Return server request
    return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}${environment.forum.topics}`);
  }
}
```

1) In `list.component.ts` you'll need to `import ServiceName from './list.service';` (or whether the service is and how it is called).

2) You'll need to include the service in the constructor of where you want to you use it: `constructor (private serv: ServiceName) { }`

3) In `submitForm()` you'll be able to do the following:

```js
this.serv.myData().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.users = data;
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => console.error(error)
    );
```

This will return you the content of whatever the server returns at `${environment.apiBaseUrl}${environment.forum.topics}`

Note: For server requests you need complete URLs (`localhost:8000/api/home`, NOT `/api/home`)

environment is basically my universal interceptor.